# C++: a macro seems to be a bit strange

Tags: c++

I've just started studying c++. Pardon for such a question.
My task is to write a macro to calculate the circumference and test it.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>

#define LENGTH(radius) (2 * M_PI * radius)

float l1 = LENGTH(1 + 2); // The result should be 18.8495... I have 8.28. Incorrect result.
float l2 = 1 / LENGTH(2); // The result should be  0.07957... Working correctly.
```

I added extra pair of parenthethis:

```
float l1 = LENGTH((1 + 2)); // Correct result.
```

How can write such a macro to I get the correct result without adding extra parentheses?

Comment: The best you could do would be to write a `constexpr` (or not) function.

Comment: What's strange here is to use a macro.  An inline function would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

use:

```
#define LENGTH(radius) (2 * M_PI * (radius))
```

When you write

```
float l1 = LENGTH(1 + 2);
```

with your define preprocessor converts it to

```
float l1 = 2 * M_PI * 1 + 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Always, always, wrap macro arguments in `()` - no matter how trivial it may seem, you will sooner or later need it.

Of course, writing a function that does the same thing has several benefits:
 1. You can step into it in the debugger, so you can actually figure out what goes on. 
 2. There is no strangeness with macro argument expressions.

To explain point two, say we have this code using your macro:

```
 // Print 10 lengths, 3, 5, 7, ... 
 int x = 3;
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
      printf("Length of radius %d is %5.2f\n", x, LENGTH(x += 2));
 }
```

Now, someone took an optimisation class, and realized that 2* something is faster to do as something + something, so rewrites your macro to be faster:

```
 #define LENGTH(radius) (((radius) + (radius)) * M_PI)
```

Now, since we have `x+=2` in the `LENGTH` macro, weird stuff happens (it becomes undefined behavior because the same variable is updated twice in the same statement [yes, I mean between two sequence points]. If there was a `length` function, it would work perfectly as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE A MACRO FOR THIS** -- an [inline function](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) is better *in every way*

But what's happening is pretty simple to undertand, and understanding it is useful to know why macros are best avoided.

```
#define LENGTH(radius) (2 * M_PI * radius)

float l1 = LENGTH(1 + 2);
```

A macro is just s simple textual substitution, so the code above gets substituted to:

```
float l1 = (2 * M_PI * 1 + 2);
```

which obviously has the wrong operator precedence.